# Graphhopper Server - Create and use a custom vehicle type

Tags: linux, routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

While browsing https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/blob/master/docs-routing.md I found the option to choose one of the preset vehicle types car, foot and bike. But unfortunately I have to calculate the duration based on vehicles with caped maximum speed (slower than a car and faster than a bike) which are also not allowed to drive on interstates.

What is the best approach to make something like this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an existing standard profile like car and reduce the speed profile and adjust the allowed highway tags. E.g. look into the [CarFlagEncoder](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util/CarFlagEncoder.java). Another (currently more complex) solution is to write a custom [FlagEncoder from scratch](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/create-new-flagencoder.md).

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for. I now also found it here [link](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/index.md) which I did not identify as what I was searching for. I will try to make a pull request for the documentation to avoid questions like mine in the future (if this is okay).